# Redirección 301 https

Tags: apache, https

tengo una web que quiero que funcione con **https**. Ya he instalado el certificado, veo que funciona añadiendo un *holamundo.html* con un "hola mundo".

El problema lo tengo porque tengo una redirección 301, este es el contenido de mi archivo index.html

```html
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
$vec = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"];
if ($vec!="www.ejemplo.com")
{ header("Location: http://www.ejemplo.com/");
  exit(0);
}
$idiomas = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? split(",", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) : array('en');
foreach( $idiomas as $lg ) {
 $lg = strtolower($lg);
    //ESPAÑOL
 if ((substr($lg,0,2) == "es") || (substr($lg,0,2) == "pt") || (substr($lg,0,2) == "ca") || (substr($lg,0,2) == "gl") || (substr($lg,0,2) == "eu")) 
 { header("Location: es/");
  exit(0);
 }; 
 > if (substr($
lg,0,2) == "en") 
 {
  header("Location: en/");
  exit(0);
 };  
}
header("Location: en/");
?>
```

No sé qué tengo que cambiar. He probado a sustituir todos los http por https, y no lo consigo. **¿Alquien me puede ayudar**? Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Has encontrado la solución?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a meter en el htaccess una redireccion forzosa:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
 RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```